# Process Memory increasing while debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio, memory-management, visual-studio-2017

I have this console program:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task[] t = 
            {
                Run()
            };
            Task.WaitAll(t);

            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        private static async Task Run()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Running");
            await Task.Delay(100);
            Run();
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason when i debug this and look at the graph for `Process Memory (MB)` it is slightly going up.

[image: Process Memory Graph]

But when i take snapshots and look at the memory usage i don't see any differences.

[image: Memory Usage snapshots]

Can anybody explain me why it's going up? 
And is there even anything i can do to keep it from going up?

***Edit:***
I tried to add an integer and increment it in run and decrement it after the Run() call.

```
static int k = 0;
private static async Task Run()
{
    k++;
    Console.WriteLine($"{k} Running");
    await Task.Delay(100);
    Run();
    k--;
}
```

Here is what it prints:

[image: Console result]

Comment: Surely that tiny increment is caused by it recursively calling itself every 0.1s so it has never left any of those other calls

Comment: @BugFinder are you sure? I am not awaiting the next run call so it should close after?

Comment: Very very sure, because it calls itself

Comment: Then i should be able to see somewhere i have 200 run methods open after 200 calls? How to prove that?

Comment: I dont believe the inbuilt performance stuff does.. But you could add a counter.. and incremented it as you enter run, and decrement it after that "run()" at the end and you'll see it just goes up.

Comment: @BugFinder i've added the question with result of your sugestion.

Comment: You would need to make sure you did that in a thread copoperative manner..  which Im guessing was not the case

Comment: @BugFinder have you even tried running this simple console program?

Comment: I did - mine said "An unhandled exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll" at your waitall.. so...

Comment: @BugFinder i don't know why you get that exception. Updated the question with the usings and namespace to show the full program.cs file.

Comment: ignoring why mine doesnt run - OK heres the logic, you fire a task which is to run Run.. which in turn calls itself.. but the wait will only apply to the first.. so.. if by your logic it isnt recursively calling itself and pending on the function it would run once and the app would finish maybe a second copy would have half started but would be in unknown state .. or.. it recursively call itself and keeps running as your display shows.. otherwise that first task had ended..

Comment: the app doesn't finish because of the `Console.ReadLine();` If i hit any key the app would finish.

Comment: @BugFinder please read the answer i provided. 
Thanks for trying to solve this problem :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently i was too fast to stop the debugging. 
After 10-15 minutes the program started to become stabile.

So when the thread count starts to become constant it will stop going up and just continue in the same amount of process memory.

[image: 50 min debugging graph]

So it must be slowly going up in the beginning because it spins up to 15 threads (Found that number in task manager under details)